# Connecting to local SQL Server CE database issue?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a connection string inside my `app.config` file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\STOCK.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;" 
         providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But I have got the following error: when accessing it:

[image]

**Note**: previously I had problem saving the data, and I changed the `.sdf` property to "Do not Copy", after that this error is happening.

Comment: is it pointing at the correct location? check http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: Now I solved the problem, just I moved the stock.sdf file to Bin/Debu folder.

Comment: From the sound of it, you've told visual studio not to copy your database file into the Debug folder when you compile. Meaning the path above probably does not contain your stock database.

Comment: After the edit I think the question should be why can't the file be found after changing the Copy to output folder to Do Not Copy as it is apparent that changing this flag caused the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Server Explorer in Visual Studio to get connection string.
Refer here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/314772/Using-Visual-Studio-to-find-a-database-connection

Hope this help.

Comment: I guess there connection string Data Source will have the path to `project path\DB.sdf`. If so then few notes: 1. During debugging your program will insert test records to original database. 2. Don't forget to change path after deployment.

Comment: Thank you @Renuiz, your suggestion is very useful and recommended.

Answer (score 4):

After changing file output to *"Do not Copy"* your `STOCK.sdf` **file will not be copied** to `\bin\Debug` directory and finally program will not find that file.

If you select *"Copy Always"* than you DB file will be always overwritten when you start debug. That's why you probably had "saving issue" - you just **getting new fresh DB copy** when starting debug again.

While selecting *"Copy if newer"* you will be able debug fine...**until you make changes (add table, record and so on) to your original** (which you probably can see in Visual Studio) `STOCK.sdf` file.

Comment: You are correct, early I have solved the problem by moving STOCK.sdf to Bin/Debug folder.

Comment: Now I have seen my saved data changes. So, copying it to debug folder is the right way of doing that?

Comment: Yes. But till you change DB structure. If you have stable schema you can manually copy DB and it will be fine. But I would use copy if newer while still making changes to DB. Just don't forget - when you change DB your program will use fresh empty database.